# react | material ui | AutoComplete | how to assign id as a value in onNewRequest

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I have an `AutoComplete` component from **material-ui** library. There is a way to show it as select with `menuItem` components:

```
const dataSource = [
  {
    text: name1,
    value: <MenuItem
      primaryText={name1}
      value={id1}
    />
  },
  {
    text: name2,
    value: <MenuItem
      primaryText={name2}
      value={id2}
    />
  }
];
```

Everything looks nice, but doesn't work. First problem is, if I choose an element from list, it never appears as field value. I can see it in form field, but to backend is send only this string I manually entered into field. I found that one of passed properties could match my needs - `onNewRequest`. There are all data I need, but still cannot find, how to assign the id I can find in `chosenRequest` object, passed to this function, to field value.

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked out the new version of MUI? The new released, (v0.15.1), includes  a 'dataSourceConfig' as a new property. This allows you to pass an array of objects into 'dataSource' and then in 'dataSourceConfig' you can set the 'text' and 'value' as explained in the API. Also, what is great is that you get passed the selected object on 'onNewRequest'!

Check out http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/auto-complete.

Answer (score 0):

to accomplish that you can use the `dataSourceConfig` as following:

```
const dataSourceConfig = {
  text: 'textKey',
  value: 'valueKey',
};
```

here are more examples https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/app/components/pages/components/AutoComplete/ExampleDataSources.js